# Postscribe can not be installed as a module in Angular 11 which needs to be used for a document.write failure based by a ad-script

Tags: javascript, angular, ads

I want to show some ads to my website. I thought it will be just - place following tag somewhere:

```
<script src="https://somewhere.to.go.com" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Unfortunately No :/ For a SPA like Angular it is not so easy, because I can´t execute  Code inside the Application. Just in the index.html. But that looks awful. So my research brought me to

[How to load external scripts dynamically in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular)

I followed the instructions, but then I got the error message:

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

So I found out this is a really tricky problem, because the third-part ad-script returns a code within a document.write command. Allright next research bring me to:

[Javascript ads in Angular templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140963/javascript-ads-in-angular-templates) or this
[Load external JS that has document.write in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474728/load-external-js-that-has-document-write-in-angular2)

Sounds like **postscribe** is the solution for my problem. But...it does NOT work. Can´t believe nobody asked this. This is just for AngularJS. I am using Angular 11 and it is not possible to add postscribe to my app.module.ts :( npm install, add by html-tag - nothing work. So my questions here:

Does it really just don´t work for me?
Is there some alternativ module for postscribe?
Is there some alternativ to get a workaround with the document.write problem?

Thanks a lot for any help and any ideas!

Comment: I stand at the same problem today that you faced at the time of asking this question. Please let me know if you found any solution to this problem?